# Disable crontab mail

Tags: linux, email, cron

By default, crontab on, for example, Debian, will mail any output of a job in your crontab to that user. How would one go about disabling this functionality?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

There are two main ways of doing this, as I discovered.

Either you set the MAILTO-variable to nothing at the start of the file:

```
MAILTO=""
```

or you redirect each cronjobs output to /dev/null:

```
<command> > /dev/null
```

The second having the advantage that output on stderr should still be mailed to you.

Comment: The second solution is much better, because that way you are still notified of any problems in crontab scripts.

Comment: >> will append data of stdout to file. It cannot be used to redirect stderr. Use 2> to redirect stderr.

Answer (score 5):

To prevent output of both stdout and stderr use the following syntax:

```
<command> > /dev/null 2>&1
```